# how to pick the first ul and it's children with the same attribute in xpath

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I have a home page that has 2 pagination section. I want to pick all pages just one time. how can I do that?

```
<div class='row row-large s-t-sm'>

   <div class='columns'>
      <div class='pagination-centered'>
         <ul class='pagination'>
            <li><a href='1.php'>1</a></li>
            <li><a href='2.php'>2</a></li>
            <li><a href='3.php'>3</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </di>

</div>
```

the same sth like this is at the bottom of the page. when I want to pick all `href` of each `<a>` inside every `<li>`, it returns null.

```
<?php
$sitecontent =  file_get_contents('www.example.com');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($sitecontent);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//(div[@class='row row-large m-t-sm']/div[@class='column']/div/ul[@class='pagination'])[1]/li/a/@href");
foreach ($nodes as $link) {
      $stackHref[]=$link->nodeValue;      
  }
var_dump($stackHref);//returns array with Zero
?>
```

Comment: Remove "[1]"? With "[1]" you pick only the first ul

Comment: @AndreyDoronin I exactly want to get first `ul` and it's children . I mean want to pick all `href` just for only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below `xpath` :-

```
(//ul[@class="pagination"])[1]//@href
```

use above `xpath` in your code as below :-

```
$nodes = $xpath->query('(//ul[@class="pagination"])[1]//@href');
```

Comment: @johnjohn you were providing `//` outside the brackets it should be `(//`..:)